# Buscador en JQuery, Ajax y PHP (Error)

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, formularios, tablas

intento crear un formulario de búsqueda de la siguiente forma:

- Por defecto aparece el historial de pedidos:

> ```
> $(document).ready(function(){
>   $.ajax({
>     type: 'POST',
>     url: 'php/cargar_historial.php'
>   })
>   .done(function(listas_rep){
>     $('#historial').html(listas_rep)
>   })
>   .fail(function(){
>     alert('Hubo un errror al cargar el historial de pedidos')
>   })
> })
> ```

Hasta aqúi, todo bien, me muestra por defecto el historial sin problemas.
Ahora, arriba de la tabla, he añadido un "form" con 4 campos para "buscar" en el historial.

```
<form..
    <th><input type="text" id="NPedido" placeholder="N Pedido"></th>
    <th><input type="text" id="Fecha" placeholder="Fecha"></td>
    <th><input type="text" id="Codigo" placeholder="Codigo"></th>
    <th><input type="text" id="Cliente" placeholder="Cliente"></th>
    <input style="width: 100%;" type="submit" id="submit" value="Buscar">
</form>
```

Al que intento realizar la búsqueda con este código.

JQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#buscar_pedidos").submit(function(){

    var id_pedido = $('#NPedido').val()

    $.ajax({
      type: 'POST',
      url: 'php/buscar_npedido.php',
      data: {'id': id_pedido}
    })
    .done(function(listas_rep){
      $("#historial").empty();
      $('#historial').html(listas_rep)
    })
    .fail(function(){
      alert('Hubo un errror al cargar los datos')
    })

  })
})
```

PHP:

```
<?php 
require_once 'conexion.php';

function getPedidosN(){

  $mysqli = getConn();
  $id = $_POST['id'];
  $query = "SELECT * FROM `historial` WHERE npedido == $id";
  $result = $mysqli->query($query);

    $indices = '<table>
                 <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th>NumP</th>
                        <th>Fecha</td>
                        <th>Codigo</th>
                        <th>Cliente</th>
                        <th>Referencia</th>
                        <th>Detalles</th>
                        <th>Lente</th>
                    </tr>
                 </thead>';

  while($row = $result->fetch_array(MYSQLI_ASSOC)){

    $indices .= '<tbody>
                    <tr>
                        <td>' .$row[npedido]. '</td>
                        <td>' .$row[fecha]. '</td>
                        <td>' .$row[cod_cliente]. '</td>
                        <td>' .$row[nombre_cliente]. '</td>
                        <td>' .$row[referencia]. '</td>
                        <td>' .$row[detalles]. '</td>
                        <td>' .$row[tipo]. '</td>
                    </tr>
                 </tbody>';
  }

  $indices .= '</table>';
  return $indices;
}

echo getPedidosN();
```

Comment: te está recargando la página cuando haces submit? según lo que tienes debería recargar la página y por eso te muestra siempre lo mismo, tienes que hacer lo mismo que [te comenté](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/191830/preventdefault-antes-de-enviar-por-php-a-bbdd-jquery/191844#191844) en tu otra pregunta sobre preventDefault

Comment: No es necesario que retornes siempre todo el encabezado <thead>...., este encabezado lo podes dejar estático en html: <table id='historial'><thead><tr>
                        <th>NumP</th>
                        <th>Fecha</td>
                        <th>Codigo</th>
                        <th>Cliente</th>
                        <th>Referencia</th>
                        <th>Detalles</th>
                        <th>Lente</th>
                    </tr>
                 </thead><tbody></tbody>,    
 y en la respuesta jQuery:  $('#historial tbody').html(listas_rep)

Comment: @Dibort Si, me recarga la página al hacer submit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tu problema es con la recarga de la página al hacer submit.
Tienes que modificar el jquery del onsubmit.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#buscar_pedidos").submit(function(e){ // Modifica esta línea
    e.preventDefault(); // Te falta esta línea
    var id_pedido = $('#NPedido').val()

    $.ajax({
      type: 'POST',
      url: 'php/buscar_npedido.php',
      data: {'id': id_pedido}
    })
    .done(function(listas_rep){
      $("#historial").empty();
      $('#historial').html(listas_rep)
    })
    .fail(function(){
      alert('Hubo un errror al cargar los datos')
    })

  })
})
```

Comment: Genial! si funciona!! muchas gracias Dibort.

Answer (score 0):

podrías colocar el log del error, o imágenes. Donde se genera el error? en la petición, respuesta, en el servidor?

Intenta cambiando esta linea:

`$query = "SELECT * FROM historial WHERE npedido == $id";`

por:

`$query = "SELECT * FROM historial WHERE npedido = $id";`

Comment: Cierto, iva a modificar la respuesta, me olvidé que tenía los ==, con un _= si que funciona. Bueno, el ajax me da .done, el problema, es que introduzco por ejemplo el valor "1" en el campo, doy a buscar, y me "actualiza" el historial de pedidos, parece como que refresca el div de #historial, pero me sigue mostrando todos los pedidos, nose si es posible que el primer jquery que muestra por defecto el historia, está haciendo conficto.

Comment: Vos necesitas que historial se refresque cuando se cambia 'N Pedido', o queres que vaya incrementando los registros en historial?

Comment: Por defecto, al entrar, carga el historial de pedidos, al buscar, únicamente debería mostrar los pedidos que devuelva la consulta del select, es decir, si pongo 1, solo debería mostrar el pedido con código 1.

Comment: Intentá, quitando el <form>, y cambiando $("#buscar_pedidos").submit, por $("#buscar_pedidos").click